# How do I publish a major version of an image?

Tags: permissions, versioning, image

I have major and minor versioning enabled on my picture library, but I can't find a way to publish a major version. Right now, users are encountering a permissions warning in place of the image.

I tried checking out an image, and I was able to set the image as a Major Version on check-in, but doing so involves two extra steps and screen draws and I'm hoping someone is aware of more efficient method for getting each of the dozens of images published...

I realize changing to a major-versions-only setting might fix the issue, but I want to keep minor versioning in place, as it theoretically allows me to put new versions of content in place for review before publishing the change...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the library to use major versions only, which immediately sets all the images to 1.0 versions, then set versioning back to major and minor.

Answer (score 0):

**If publishing Images library**
In thumbsnail view select the image then in the ribbon select:

> Document Ribbon Tab | Workflows Group | Publish

Or in the All Asserts view in the dropdown next to the name select "Publish a Major Version"

**If Foundation picture library**
Select Detail version of current view
[image]
In the dropdown next to the name select "Publish a Major Version"
[image]

Comment: In thumbnail view, selecting the image (via the checkbox, correct?) doesn't generate the ribbon...

I don't have an "all assets" view, but I created a view as a list, rather than a thumbnail "gallery", but there was no "Publish a Major Version" command present.

Please revisit the OP, as I have added additional information.

Thanks, Per!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have "Publish" as an option. I tried multiple images... http://i.imgur.com/bFtyW.jpg

Comment: Maybe you need to enable the publish feature

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered building a quick Workflow via SharePoint Designer to perform the bulk operation for you? (I also assume you do have appropriate permissions on the SP Site to Approve items)

Publish does not work on multiple Items, only Check-In (if you disable minor all files go to Major immediately).

The fastest (because is one time and no-code solution) would be a Powershell script see here for exact examples but with files - same stuff - http://www.aarebrot.net/site/index.php/branding/15

Comment: I'm not at all versed in workflows and can't make it a priority at this time. This is also kind of a one-off instance; we rarely have a need to publish major versions of so many files, although this is a job I plan to explore for future tasks. Thanks, C!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to right click on the name of the file and then check in.  Then it will allow you to publish a major version.

Comment: I've been checking files out and in to access the "Publish a Major Version" function in the check-in interface. I'm trying to access the "Publish a Major Version" selection that, while available in every other library, isn't available as an option in my images library.

When you say right-click, do you mean in the browser? Because right-clicking on the name of a file in the browser brings up the browser's contextual menu, not a SharePoint menu...

Comment: Not in the browser, in sharepoint designer